# c++ code compiles without errors but gives a `Segmentation fault` while running

Tags: c++, constructor, segmentation-fault, destructor

I cannot understand my problem. I have files:

/* main.C */

```
#include <iostream>
#include "point.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Point p_default;
    p_default.print();

    Point p_equal(2.5);
    p_equal.print();

    Point p_full(1.23, 2.4, 0.18);
    p_full.print();

    return 0;
}
```

/* point.h  */

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Point {
    double x, y, z;
    double* arr;

public:
    // constructors
    Point (); // default
    Point (double); // equal arguments 
    Point (double _x, double _y, double _z); // standard

    // destructor
    ~Point ();

    // print function
    void print () const;
};
```

/* point.C  */

```
#include <iostream>
#include "point.h"

using namespace std;

// constructors
Point::Point () : Point(0.0) {}; // default - zero initialised
Point::Point (double _c) : Point(_c, _c, _c) {}; // equal arguments 

// standard constructor
Point::Point (double _x, double _y, double _z = 0.0)
: x(_x), y(_y), z(_z) {
    double* arr = nullptr;

    arr = new double[3];

    *arr = x;
    *(arr + 1) = y;
    *(arr + 2) = z;
};

// destructor
Point::~Point () {
    delete[] arr;
};

// print function
void Point::print () const {
    cout << "Point(" << x << ", " << y << ", " << z << ")" << endl;
};
```

I compile my project with the following command: `g++ -Wall -std=c++11 main.C point.C -o main`. It compiles without any error or warning but when I run it with `./main` it prints everything correctly and in the end gives me `Segmentation fault`:

```
Point(0, 0, 0)
Point(2.5, 2.5, 2.5)
Point(1.23, 2.4, 0.18)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I assume it has a relation to my destructor but cannot understand where the problem is.

Comment: Why do you need `arr` at all? And even if so, it should be `std::array<double,3> arr;`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ because `Point` is an array.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (`g++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 -g main.C point.C -o main`) then **use the debugger** (`gdb`) and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) if available. With a recent GCC, consider also passing `-fsanitize=address` to `g++`

Comment: Also, better use standard C++ containers and smart pointers.

Comment: @Alexandr: no, `Point` is not an array, but a `class`. Be aware of the [C++11 rule of five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch `gdb` gives me `Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0xb7d89ca0 in __GI___libc_free (mem=0x8048b4b) at malloc.c:2945 2945 malloc.c: No such file or directory.`

Comment: You need to also use `valgrind` and/or perhaps compile with `-fsanitize=address` and you probably should not use raw arrays, but standard C++ containers (or smart pointers).

Comment: You forgot the copy constructor and assignment operator that `Point` needs.

Comment: @Alexandr If you insist to manage memory yourself (which is a bit stupid decision IMHO), you also should initialize `arr` to `nullptr` in the default constructor, amongst correct handling for copy construction and assignment.

Comment: thank you, guys. I will try using `<array>`.

Comment: @molbdnilo thank you. I will implement that as well.

Comment: You are more than half done: First it doesn't compile. Then it compiles, but doesn't link. Then it compiles, links but crashes. Then it compiles, links, runs but doesn't do what you want. Then, and only then, it compiles, links, runs and does what you want it to do.

Comment: @molbdnilo this code doesn't do any copy or assignment operations though, so it is not the cause of the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// standard constructor
Point::Point (double _x, double _y, double _z = 0.0)
: x(_x), y(_y), z(_z) {
    // This is local, yet you are deleting the non-initialized member
    // in your destructor!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    double* arr = nullptr;

    arr = new double[3];

    *arr = x;
    *(arr + 1) = y;
    *(arr + 2) = z;
};
```

See my comment in the code...

Apart from this your code has many problems:

- Default copy constructor is not sufficient.
- Underscore as prefix reserved for the standard.
- Use std containers (e.g vector or array) instead of trying to manage
  memory yourself.
- Why have an array in the first place? Aren't the member variables x,y,z good enough?

Regards, Werner

Comment: He doesn't even need containers though. Just plain array will be enough. Also he might want to be able to access members by index AND by name, which is normally a job for union. That's the only explanation (I can think of) for "arr" variable.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is, that you never initialize your datamember "arr" of your Point class. The

```
double* arr = nullptr;

arr = new double[3];
```

in your constructor creates a local pointer "arr" and initializes the local pointer, but not your class member "arr".
When you try to delete "arr" in your destructor, you try to delete the "arr" of your class, which never got allocated and initialized.

Comment: It's not the only problem of that class, but well spotted, yes.